# How to ping several IP addresses without using the same line of code for every IP address?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to ping several IPs a not all at once but one by one.
My problem is that I do not want to use the same if else clause for every IP address.
As you can see I have only done it for  `10.10.10.5`
but i do not want to repeat it for every other IP i know it is bad practice but i have no idea how to write a algorithm or something similar for it.
I also need to send this info (PASS/FAIL) to a MariaDB database.
Could someone please show me how i can write an algorithm or a function to iterate through the IPs but still save the result of each IP and send it to the database.
Examples would be much appreciated

```
   def pingPreflash(self):
        self.reachable = 'PASS'
        self.unreachable = 'FAIL'
        self.preflash = subprocess.run(["ping","-n","2", "10.10.10.2"],stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.p1 = subprocess.run(["ping","-n","2", "192.168.11.10"],stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.p2 = subprocess.run(["ping","-n","2", "192.168.12.10"],stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.p3 = subprocess.run(["ping","-n","2", "192.168.13.10"],stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.p4 = subprocess.run(["ping","-n","2", "192.168.14.10"],stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.software = subprocess.run(["ping","-n","2", "192.168.100.2"],stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        if self.preflash.returncode == 0:
            if("unreachable" in str(self.preflash.stdout)):
                self.preflashesult = self.unreachable
                print('10.10.10.5', self.preflashesult)
            else:
                self.preflashesult = self.reachable
                print('10.10.10.5', self.preflashesult)
        elif self.preflash.returncode == 1:
            self.preflashesult = self.unreachable
            print('10.10.10.5', self.preflashesult)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you've answered your own question by saying you need 'to iterate'. You should put the ip addresses in a list and iterate over them:

```
ip_addressses = [.....]
for ip in ip_addresses:
    supprocess.run(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over a `list` of ip addresses, and then run your lohic using a `match` statement against the output of your `subprocess` call.

From there you can write to the DB if required.

```
def pingPreflash(self):

        ip_list = ['10.10.10.2', '192.168.11.10', '192.168.12.10', '192.168.13.10', '192.168.14.10', '192.168.100.2']

        for ip in ip_list:
            output = subprocess.run(["ping","-n","2", ip],stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

            match output.returncode:
                case 0:
                    if 'unreachable' in str(output.stdout):
                        print(ip, 'unReachable')
                    else:
                        print(ip, 'Reachable')
                case 1:
                    print(ip, 'unReachable')
```

Python <3.10:

```
def pingPreflash(self):

        ip_list = ['10.10.10.2', '192.168.11.10', '192.168.12.10', '192.168.13.10', '192.168.14.10', '192.168.100.2']

        for ip in ip_list:
            output = subprocess.run(["ping","-n","2", ip],stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

            if output.returncode == 0:
                if 'unreachable' in str(output.stdout):
                    print(ip, 'unReachable')
                else:
                    print(ip, 'Reachable')
            elif output.returncode == 1:
                print(ip, 'unReachable')
```

If you want to store the output, you can assign the result to a `dict` and use the `ip` as the `key`.

```
def pingPreflash(self):

        ip_list = ['10.10.10.2']

        all_status = {}
        for ip in ip_list:
            output = subprocess.run(["ping","-n","2", ip],stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

            if output.returncode == 0:
                if 'unreachable' in str(output.stdout):
                    all_status[ip] = 'FAIL'
                else:
                    all_status[ip] = 'PASS'
            elif output.returncode == 1:
                all_status[ip] = 'FAIL'

        return all_status
```

Outputs

```
pingPreflash(1)
{'10.10.10.2': 'FAIL'}
```

Comment: Note that the `match` statement requires python 3.10

Comment: I like how someone named PacketLoss answered a question in such a perfection about ping.

Comment: You are right, I cannot use python3.10 for my project because of certain restrictions of the project. is there another way to use match here an alternative function?
but @PacketLoss thank you very much that was helpful

Comment: @Ramas I have added a section without using match statements

Comment: @PacketLoss I did something like this ``` self.ips = ["192.168.{}.10".format(i) for i in range(11,15)]``` to iterate through the list of ips. 
But how do i assign either PASS or FAIL string value to every  IP number. I need to assign a variable to each ip number so i can put it in the database

Comment: @Ramas I have added an option to the bottom of the answer